# Nuxt data pre-loading with localStorage

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, local-storage, vuex

#### I have a question about possibilities of data pre-loading with nuxt.js

---

I'm currently working on a project that is strongly coupled with back-end data and I stumbled on some difficulties.

I would like to save some data in localStorage to speed up the navigation within my website, the data consist of dictionaries containing (key: value) pairs that I use to resolve item properties names that come from api calls on query for specific item. *(oh and they can possibly change in the future with more languages coming)*

When the `localStorage` wasn't initiated (first visit/storage cleared/disabled) I would like to fetch that data to Vuex store so I can use store getters in Vue components.

Some problems emerge with my approach as `localStorage` is available from `mounted()` and not before that point in components life cycle. So I can't detect if there is any cached data before the whole page is already rendered.

###### I would like to hear any ideas, is there any workaround, maybe this way of cashing data is simply wrong. I'm just at the beginning of front-end journey.

---

*Sidenote - I have wrote a custom plugin for async calls to api but Nuxt renders all components before I even commit the chages to Vuex store.*

Comment: Interesting.. As this is mostly theoretical question asking about how things should be done not how to fix one particular problem.

Comment: Hence why I voted to close this question because those kind of questions are not allowed on SO (how-to/tutorials/recommendations). You should be coming with some code and/or an issue.

Comment: Do you want to persist the data to Vuex or local storage, because data on Vuex disappears once a page is refreshed